# quirky rails routing not respecting form or config parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`rake routes` shows

```
create_multiple_allotments POST   /allotments/create_multiple(.:format)                allotments#create_multiple
```

the form calls

```
<%= form_tag create_multiple_allotments_path, :method => :post do %>
```

yet, submitting the form goes off on its own:

```
Started GET "/allotments/create_multiple? [...]
Processing by AllotmentsController#show as HTML
```

routes defines

```
  resources :allotments do
    collection do
      post  :create_multiple
    end
  end
```

why is rails insisting on doing a get?

Comment: Just guessing, the convention in rails application is to render the newly created record using show method

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the source of the problem.

the form had erroneously a `get` method specified earlier.  Changed routing and form.  But the browser cache was served up and still sending the old setup.

Silly...